# Botón de guardar la pagina se recarga y se pierde el valor que estaba seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un select con dos `option`, lo que hace ahora es hacer `display none and block` dependiendo del valor del `select`. El problema que tengo es que cuando le doy al botón de guardar la pagina se recarga y se pierde el valor que estaba seleccionado. Dejo el código que tengo por ahora.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
//console.log( this.value );
if(this.value == 'comp'){
    $('#empl_id').css("display", "none");
    $('div#comp_id').css("display", "block");
}else if(this.value == 'empl'){
    $('div#com_id').css("display", "none");
    $("#empl_id").css("display", "block");
}
});
```

Comment: Tendrías que evitar el `submit` para que no recargue la página. supongo quieres mandar los datos al `backend` sin recargar, cierto?

Comment: Al guardar el envio lo hace via ajax??? o por form:submit???

Comment: Tengo unos filtros, lo hago via ajax. No se podria guardar el ultimo value y asignarlo cuando se actualiza la pagina?

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración de código deben incluir un [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo guardándolo en el [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Ejemplo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/de684m7L/):

```
<select name="seleccion" id="">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  </select>

  <div id="cuadro" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">

  </div>
    <script>

    if (typeof(localStorage) === "undefined") {
        alert("no soporta localstorage")
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('background-color')) {
        let color = localStorage.getItem('background-color');
        $("#cuadro").css("background-color", color);
        $(`option[value="${color}"]`).attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    $('select').on('change', function() {
        //console.log( this.value );
        if (this.value == 'red') {
            $("#cuadro").css("background-color", "red");
            localStorage.setItem('background-color', 'red');
        } else if (this.value == 'green') {
            $("#cuadro").css("background-color", "green");
            localStorage.setItem('background-color', 'green');
        }else{
            $("#cuadro").css("background-color", "yellow");
            localStorage.setItem('background-color', 'yellow');
        }
});
</script>
```

Si lo deseas, puedes crear una función para mayor facilidad:

```
function local(attribute,value=null){
    if(value)
        return localStorage.setItem(attribute,value);
    return localStorage.getItem(attribute);
}
// set property
local('background-color', 'yellow');
// get property
local('background-color');
```